# SQL can't run UPDATE query because a table is specified twice

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to SQL and I couldn't make great use of other similar questions.

I am trying to give a 30% discount to all people who share the same house, so I have a table with an ID, a price and a house name.

This was my query:

```
UPDATE person
SET price= price*0.97
WHERE house IN (SELECT p.house FROM person p GROUP BY p.house HAVING COUNT(*) >2);
```

It says "Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data" but I know no other methods to save the string of the house and compare the other voices.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

This is a limitation in MySQL.  The solution is to use a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE person p JOIN
       (SELECT p.house
        FROM person p
        GROUP BY p.house
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
       ) ph
       ON p.house = ph.house
    SET p.price = p.price * 0.97;
```

The `JOIN` does the filtering instead of the `IN` operator.